# How to publish a PowerBI report that Contains millions of records in multiple Fact tables

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

My PowerBI report contains multiple fact tables and those are having more than 10 millions records in each tables. Whenever I am trying to publish it , its throwing "Out of memory execution" error or else it is taking more than 1 hour . Is there any alternative way to publish this report and handle this huge dataset. Is it possible to reduce dataset before publishing and after publishing, the whole dataset can be refreshed to its original form.

Comment: Do you have star schema? Can you ride off some of your columns/rows? Did you make some changes/transformations in M Language (Transform Data Tab) or you just import data from source?

Comment: Yes Star Schema. I have considered only the required columns only. Yes I have directly import data from tables only.